# Calling anonymous function from a pointer

Tags: delphi, anonymous-function, delphi-xe7

I get an access violation while trying to call an anonymous method from a `Pointer` variable

```
var
  Proc : TProc;
  Pt : Pointer;
begin
  Proc := procedure
  begin
    ShowMessage('Hello World');
  end;

  Pt := @Proc;
  TProc(Pt)();
end;
```

In debug I see that `Pt` is evalued

Comment: This isn't going to end well, but what you are doing is akin to `P := @SomeInt; X := Integer(P)`. You took the address of the anon. So you'd need to dereference that address. But as I said, this is very likely not going to end well. Presumably in your real code you want to store that pointer somewhere. Doing so goes behind the back of reference counting. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Dereferencing worked well `TProc(Pt^)();`. Thanks for the warnings, as soon my `Proc` variable will goes out of scope then the pointer will not be safe to use. I was just playing without any real plan, but I wasn't understanding the access violation

Comment: @Fabrizio: Correct. You can get into the same kind of trouble if you mess with other managed types, such as strings and dynamic arrays. Just don't do that!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand And records

Comment: @Bitman: Not POD records. Only records that contain managed types (like strings). POD records are simple value types like integers or static arrays of integers.

Comment: (But, regarding my second comment, in this case you only get the address of a local variable. So you can get the same kind of problem even with unmanaged types. For instance, take the address of a local integer variable and try to use it after the function has returned.)

Comment: Probably your confusion comes from this: If `F` is a regular function, then `@F` is the address of this function. But in your case, `pt` is only a pointer to the `Proc` *local variable*.